# Riemann-integrable and boundedness

Tags: calculus, integration

If $f\in \mathcal{R} [a,b]$ and $\left| f(x) \right|\le M$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ , then
$$\left|\int_a^b f dx \right|\le M(b-a)$$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

Is it sufficient if i just do the following to prove it?

$f$ is bounded and Riemann-integrable, so
$$-M \le f(x) \le M$$ then $$-M(b-a) \le \int_a^b f(x) dx\le M(b-a)$$

Comment: Your right-hand-side should be $M(b-a)$ of course.  repaired.

Comment: Yeah, it looks fine. I would add that you took the partition $P = \{a, b\}$ to get the last inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Mh that depends on what you already know. You are using the monoticity of the integral, so when $f\geq g$ than $$
\int_a^b f\, \mathrm{d} x \geq \int_a^b g \, \mathrm{d} x$$
If you already know it, it will be fine, if not you have to prove it, to help you here I need to know how you define the integral.